# Write a function that reads a txt file, containing Athlete's names and scores. Calculating and returning the highest average score

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that reads a txt document containing names with corresponding scores(floats), eg. Li Ning, 9.8 9.7 9.6 9.3 9.4 9.8. Each name (competitors) and corresponding numbers are on a newline in the doc. Function should return the highest average score, and the corresponding name. Average scores are to be calculated. The average score of a contestant is computed after discarding the best and worst scores.

```
def getWinner(filename): 
    results = open(filename).readlines()        
    winner = ''   
    max_score =0 
    for line in results:
        tokens = line.split(',')    
        name =  tokens[0]                
        scores = map(float, tokens[1].split()) 
        ave = sum(scores[1:-1])/(len(scores) - 2)                    
        if ave > max_score:
           winner = name             
           max_score = ave         
    return "%s [%.1f]" % (winner, max_score)
```

This is a a learning activity provided by an online interactive python school, pyschools. I am returning the correct result in the output, but it's also returning "private test cases failed"
Can anyone see any serious flaws in the code here? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was that you weren't sorting the list before slicing off the first and last items. You can fix this by casting `sorted` to your map (`scores`).

```
def getWinner(filename): 
    results = open(filename).readlines()        
    winner = ''   
    max_score =0 
    for line in results:
        tokens = line.split(',')    
        name =  tokens[0]                
        scores = sorted(map(float, tokens[1].split()))
        ave = sum(scores[1:-1])/(len(scores) - 2)                    
        if ave > max_score:
           winner = name             
           max_score = ave         
    return "%s [%.1f]" % (winner, max_score)
```

Previously, the code would return:

```
>>> getWinner('file.txt')
'Li Ning [9.5]'
>>>
```

Which is wrong because:

```
>>> x = '9.8 9.7 9.6 9.3 9.4 9.8'
>>> x = sorted(map(float, x.split()))[1:-1]
>>> sum(x)/len(x)
9.625
>>>
```

The edited code returns:

```
>>> getWinner('file.txt')
'Li Ning [9.6]'
>>>
```

Which is correct, because string formatting rounds to the first digit.